# Как получить chatID в Telegram?

Tags: golang, telegram-bot, telegram

Я впервые пишу бота для Telegram.
Он должен отправлять личные сообщения списку пользователей по chatID.
Как мне получить chatID?

Заранее благодарю!

**ОБНОВЛЕНО**

Я в курсе того, что можно отправить сообщение боту, бот получит в сообщении chatID.
Можно как то не используя API бота достать этот chatID?

Comment: Какой язык/библиотеку/фреймворк используете?

Comment: посмотрите этот ответ https://stackoverflow.com/a/32572159/5634351

Comment: язык go, библиотека github.com/Syfaro/telegram-bot-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рассмотрим на примере объекта [Message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message), посылаемого пользователем боту.

Каждое сообщение - это объект, содержащий в себе некоторые поля, в частности - нужное нам [chat](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chat). Это поле, в свою очередь, тоже является объектом и тоже содержит поля, в том числе и нужное нам *id*. Получать его можно по-разному, в зависимости от того, как реализована работа с API.

**Пример для Go:**

В данном примере бот пишет в лог идентификатор чата и текст сообщения (взято из [примера](https://github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api#example) и немного доработано)

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "gopkg.in/telegram-bot-api.v4"
)

func main() {
    bot, err := tgbotapi.NewBotAPI("MyAwesomeBotToken")
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    bot.Debug = true

    u := tgbotapi.NewUpdate(0)
    u.Timeout = 60

    updates, err := bot.GetUpdatesChan(u)

    for update := range updates {
        if update.Message == nil {
            continue
        }

        log.Printf("[%s] %s", update.Message.Chat.ID, update.Message.Text)
    }
}
```

---

Обычное сообщение может являться текстовым сообщением, посылаемым файлом, стикером, фото, видео или аудио. Есть так же другие типы объектов, получаемых ботом от пользователя - они перечислены в качестве полей объекта [Update](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update). В зависимости от типа объекта логика получения идентификатора чата может немного различаться.

Comment: Я смогу сделать это, работая с локального компьютера?

Comment: @ДмитрийМатвиенко конечно, а почему нет?

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо за пример кода!

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить chat ID пользователя, вы можете использовать метод getUpdates из API Telegram. Этот метод возвращает список обновлений, то есть список сообщений, которые бот получил с момента последнего вызова этого метода. Каждое сообщение содержит информацию об авторе сообщения, в том числе chat ID.

Например, чтобы получить chat ID пользователя, который отправил боту сообщение, вы можете использовать следующий код:

```
import requests
import json

TOKEN = 'your_bot_token'

def get_chat_id(update):
    chat_id = update['message']['chat']['id']
    return chat_id

def get_updates():
    url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/getUpdates'
    response = requests.get(url)
    return json.loads(response.content)

updates = get_updates()
chat_id = get_chat_id(updates[0])
print(chat_id)
```

Обратите внимание, что этот код получает только первое сообщение из списка обновлений, так что если вы хотите получить chat ID для нескольких пользователей, вам нужно будет обработать. Остальные сообщения из списка обновлений можно, например, так:

```
import requests
import json

TOKEN = 'your_bot_token'

def get_chat_id(update):
    chat_id = update['message']['chat']['id']
    return chat_id

def get_updates():
    url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/getUpdates'
    response = requests.get(url)
    return json.loads(response.content)

updates = get_updates()
for update in updates:
    chat_id = get_chat_id(update)
    print(chat_id)
```

Обратите внимание, что getUpdates возвращает только те сообщения, которые бот еще не обработал. Чтобы получить все сообщения, вам нужно будет указать опцию offset, которая указывает, с какого сообщения нужно начать получение обновлений. Например:

```
import requests
import json

TOKEN = 'your_bot_token'

def get_chat_id(update):
    chat_id = update['message']['chat']['id']
    return chat_id

def get_updates(offset):
    url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/getUpdates?offset={offset}'
    response = requests.get(url)
    return json.loads(response.content)

updates = get_updates(0)
for update in updates:
    chat_id = get_chat_id(update)
    print(chat_id)

updates = get_updates(updates[-1]['update_id'] + 1)
for update in updates:
    chat_id = get_chat_id(update)
    print(chat_id)
```

Еще один способ получить chat ID без использования API бота - это использовать веб-версию Telegram. Вы можете открыть любое сообщение, которое вы отправили боту, и скопировать chat ID из адресной строки браузера. Он будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
https://web.telegram.org/#/im?p=@your_bot_username&startparam=1234567890
```

Где `1234567890` - это chat ID.

Обратите внимание, что этот способ получения chat ID не подходит, если вы хотите получить chat ID для нескольких пользователей. В этом случае вам нужно будет вручную скопировать chat ID для каждого пользователя.

Чтобы отправить личное сообщение пользователю через бота, вам нужно знать chat ID этого пользователя. Один из способов получения chat ID - это использование метода getUpdates из API Telegram. Давайте рассмотрим, как отправить сообщение пользователю с помощью этого метода.

Для начала, нужно установить библиотеку requests, которая позволяет отправлять HTTP-запросы из Python. Это можно сделать с помощью команды pip install requests.

Затем, используя метод sendMessage из API Telegram, можно отправить сообщение пользователю со следующим кодом:

```
import requests

TOKEN = 'your_bot_token'
CHAT_ID = '1234567890' # Замените на реальный chat ID
MESSAGE = 'Hello, World!'

url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendMessage'
params = {
    'chat_id': CHAT_ID,
    'text': MESSAGE
}
response = requests.post(url, params=params)
print(response.status_code)
```

Обратите внимание, что в качестве параметра chat_id нужно указывать chat ID пользователя

Например, чтобы отправить сообщение списку пользователей, вы можете использовать следующий код:

```
import requests
import json

TOKEN = 'your_bot_token'
MESSAGE = 'Hello, World!'

def get_chat_id(update):
    chat_id = update['message']['chat']['id']
    return chat_id

def get_updates():
    url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/getUpdates'
    response = requests.get(url)
    return json.loads(response.content)

def send_message(chat_id, message):
    url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendMessage'
    params = {
        'chat_id': chat_id,
        'text': message
    }
    response = requests.post(url, params=params)
    return response.status_code

updates = get_updates()
chat_ids = [get_chat_id(update) for update in updates]
for chat_id in chat_ids:
    send_message(chat_id, MESSAGE)
```

В этом коде мы обрабатываем все сообщения, полученные с помощью getUpdates, и для каждого сообщения получаем chat ID пользователя. Затем мы создаем список этих chat ID и используем его для отправки сообщения всем этим пользователям с помощью send_message.

Обратите внимание, что этот код отправит сообщение только тем пользователям, с которыми бот уже общался